# Copy and pasting a line into a chart using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, excel-charts

First time using this site. Borrowing an idea from the SpreadSheetGuru, I am copy and pasting bunch of drawn shapes into a temporary chart such that I can save them as a PNG image. I copy and paste different shapes, one by one, and then move them using Top and Left properties so they look like the original arrangement. It works great for rectangles and textboxes but gives me an error for lines (straight connectors). It says “the item with specified name wasn’t found” but I do not use anything different. I appreciate your help to solve this problem. Here is that part of the code below. The lines are copied and pasted, as I can see them when I step through the code, but cannot be "addressed" to be moved to their correct location on the chart

```
k = 0
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes        ' ---------------------------------------- select one shape at a time
          a1 = InStr(1, Trim(sh.Name), "TextBox", 1)
          A2 = InStr(1, Trim(sh.Name), "Rectangle", 1)
          a3 = InStr(1, Trim(sh.Name), "Straight", 1)
          a4 = InStr(1, Trim(sh.Name), "Line", 1)
          If a1 > 0 Or A2 > 0 Or a3 > 0 Or a4 > 0 Then
            sh.Select
            k = k + 1
          Else: GoTo NextShape:
          End If

sh.Name = sh.Name & k

        'Copy/Paste Shape inside temporary chart
          ActiveShape.Copy
          cht.Activate
          ActiveChart.Paste

          ActiveChart.Shapes(UserSelection.Name).Top = ActiveShape.Top - Top0  '  ===  ERROR IS HERE
          ActiveChart.Shapes(UserSelection.Name).Left = ActiveShape.Left - Left0
 
NextShape:
Next sh   ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What are ActiveShape and UserSelection ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of different approaches. Both are pasting the shapes into a chart inserted on the worksheet (ie. I'm not using a chart sheet)

```vb
Sub CopyShapesToChart()
    
    Dim sh, cht As Chart, e, shp, col As New Collection
    Dim minY, minX, maxY, maxX, v

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    
    minY = 1000000# 'set starting points (random high number)
    minX = 1000000#
    
    'First collect all of the shapes we're interested in,
    '  and figure out the "bounding box" for them
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        For Each e In Array("TextBox", "Rectangle", "Straight", "Line")
            If InStr(1, shp.Name, e) > 0 Then
                'tracking bounding box for all shapes
                If shp.Top < minY Then minY = shp.Top
                If shp.Left < minX Then minX = shp.Left
                v = shp.Top + shp.Height
                If v > maxY Then maxY = v
                v = shp.Left + shp.Width
                If v > maxX Then maxX = v
                col.Add shp
                Exit For
            End If
         Next e
    Next shp
    
    'resize the chartobject to fit the collection of shapes
    cht.Parent.Height = maxY - minY
    cht.Parent.Width = maxX - minX
    
    'copy each shape into the chart
    For Each shp In col
        shp.Copy
        cht.Paste
        With cht.Shapes(cht.Shapes.Count)
            .Top = shp.Top - minY
            .Left = shp.Left - minX
        End With
    Next shp
    
    'now export the chart...

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: a second approach with a little less work - instead of copying shapes one-by-one group all of them and copy them in one operation

```vb
Sub CopyShapesToChart2()
    
    Dim sh, cht As Chart, e, shp
    Dim arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long, rng
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    
    ReDim arr(0 To ws.Shapes.Count)
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        For Each e In Array("TextBox", "Rectangle", "Straight", "Line")
            If InStr(1, shp.Name, e) > 0 Then
                arr(i) = shp.Name
                i = i + 1
                Exit For
            End If
         Next e
    Next shp
    If i > 0 Then            'matched any shapes?
        If i > 1 Then        'matched>1 shape?
            ReDim Preserve arr(0 To i - 1)
            Set rng = ws.Shapes.Range(arr).Group() 'group the matched shapes
        Else
            Set rng = ws.Shapes(arr(0)) 'just matched a single shape
        End If
        'resize the chartobject to fit the [collection of] shape[s]
        cht.Parent.Height = rng.Height
        cht.Parent.Width = rng.Width
        rng.Copy   'copy the shape or group
        cht.Paste
        If i > 1 Then rng.Ungroup 'ungroup if we grouped anything
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your code to group and transfer shapes. I tried it but get  runtime error 1004 "Method ChartObjects of _Worksheet failed" on the "Set  cht" statement. I am trying whatever I know but cannot get rid of that error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I was using a chart inserted onto a worksheet, not a chart sheet.  I will update to add that.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine (Ray Hayes) provided the answer off line. To make the original code work, all is needed is to change "UserSelection.Name" to "Selection.Name".